# C++: cannot assign vector of pointer to another vector of pointer

Tags: c++

I have `class Student` (`studentOwner`) and `class Section`.
Here is my class `Student`:

```
class Student {
  vector<Section*> enrolledSections;
public:
  vector<Section*> getEnrolledSections() const { return enrolledSections; }
}
```

So, when I get `vector<Section*>` and assign to another vector, I will meet error. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
// first example: no error, if take size of vector
int a = studentOwner->getEnrolledSections().size();
// second example: error, when only take its vector and assign again
// Error: no suitable user-define conversion from "std::vector<error-type" ....
vector<Section*> enrolled = studentOwner->getEnrolledSections();
// third example: error when take this vector and assign to reference of same type
// Error: initial value of reference to non-const value must be lvalue
vector<Section*>& enrolled = studentOwner->getEnrolledSections();
```

Full error at second example is:

```
Error: no suitable user-define conversion from "std::vector<error-type", std::alocator<<error-type> *>> "to " std::vector<Section*, std::allocator<Section*>>" exists
```

In many class of my project, I cannot do line two and line three and received same error. I cannot explain by myself. Please teach me at this point.

Thanks :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Error i post in code section. please review it for me :)

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional, but be aware that you're returning _copies_ of the vector.

Comment: Regarding the straight assignment of to a vector, what is the _full_ error message? You _do_ have declared the `Section` class when you do that assignment?

Comment: in class Student, getEnrolleSections() should be getEnrolledSections()?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited my question for full erorr. please review it for me. Thanks:)

Comment: As I see it there are two possibilities: The first is that you don't include the header file where `Section` is defined; The second is that you have other errors that prevents the definition of the `Section` class. Are there errors _before_ that error?

Comment: Is the code posted your actual code?  I see that you haven't specified the scope of vector (as in std::vector) in your header so either that isn't the real code, or you are using namespace std; in your header which is a no-no.

Comment: Yep.  Write a minimal complete and compiling example of your error.  We should be able to copy paste it to Ideone. com and it should compile or not there.

Comment: @Aesthete It's *not necessarily* the case that a copy is made, due to potential  [copy elision to implement return-value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).  This is sometimes true in C++03.  But in C++11 the support of move construction in standard library objects via [rvalue references / move construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) is implemented to where you're absolutely *not* making a copy.  (Which is nifty.)

Comment: @RyanGuthrie I think the problem I might found is because: header `Section` include header `Course`, and header `Course` include again header `Section`. So, how can I fix this ? because they depend together

Comment: @hqt Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @hqt One way to avoid 'circular includes' is using pointers or references to the other class and forward-declaring it. Of course, it implies other cares with the memory management, but used correctly it can even improve your compilation times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you see `error-type` in MSVC errors, it's a result of a forward declared type that wasn't included in time for that compilation unit. For example,

```
// Course.h
class Student;

class Course {
     [...]
public:
     Student* getStudent();
}

// Course.cpp
#include "Course.h"

Student* Course::getStudent()
{
    return new Student("Name");  //< Whoops, we never included Student.h!
}
```

In the comments you indicate a circular include dependency. As @Daniel Castro noted, you should forward declare in your header files to avoid the circular includes, then include the needed header files in your .cpp files (note the forward declaration `class Student;` above if you're not familiar).

As an aside, I would also note some design issues with your example. Returning `std::vector<Section*>` doesn't tell much about who owns what. If I get a `std::vector` by value from a function, the convention is that I now *own* the vector and its contents. If I own something, then I'm responsible for deleting it. Without seeing your actual implementation, most coders would be surprised to learn they shouldn't delete the contents of the vector. I would suggest either returning the vector by `const&` (eg, `const vector<Section*>&`) which prevents client code from manipulating the vector (so clients don't *own* it), or using [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to manage a shared ownership scheme of your `Section` objects:

```
class Student {
    vector<shared_ptr<Section>> enrolledSections_;
public:
    vector<shared_ptr<Section>> getEnrolledSections() const { return enrolledSections_; }
}
```

Now it's clear who owns what. More than you were asking for, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the vector as a reference, otherwise the vector is copied on return. Also your function is const, so you have to return the vector as const too.

```
class Student 
{
  std::vector<Section*> enrolledSections;
public:
  const std::vector<Section*> &getEnrolledSections() const { return enrolledSections; }
}
```

now you should be able to

```
const std::vector<Section*>& enrolled = studentOwner->getEnrolledSections();
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. It's most likely that @hqt doesn't have the correct include headers.